# Speed of pseudo-inverse (with possibly ill-conditioned matrices)

Tags: convergence-divergence, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra

I am computing the pseudo-inverse of several matrices of identical size $m \times n$ .  However, computation (e.g. with the LAPACK pinv) seems to be much slower in some cases (5 to 10 times slower).  I observe the same effect for several values of $m \in 100 \dots 5000$, but the effect is more important with $n \approx 100$.

Is there any theoretical/empirical result which explains what can influence the computational speed of pseudo-inverse computation ?  I have the suspicion that some of the matrices may be ill-conditioned.  Could it be related ?

Thanks !

Comment: What are you computing the pseudoinverse for?